# Angular input date across IE, Chrome & Mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, internet-explorer

I am fairly new to Angular and I am developing an Angular web-app which needs to work across IE11, Chrome and mobile.

I have the following HTML:

```
<input ng-model="myDate" type="date"/>
```

Which has the desired behaviour on mobile and Chrome. To make it work on IE11 I have imported HTML5 forms via:

```
<script src="bower_components/html5Forms.js/shared/js/html5Forms.js" data-webforms2-support="date" data-webforms2-force-js-validation="true" data-lang="qq"></script>
```

For IE11 this at least brings up a calendar, however if I do

```
console.log($scope.myDate);
```

it does not pick up the value that the IE calendar had selected, leading me to believe it doesn't work the angular way. If I gave the input element an ID and use document.getElementById I can retrieve the value. For Chrome it does print out the scope value, and can only assume it does for mobile too.

My question is then how do I make the type="date" work across all 3 instances? Am I perhaps using the html5Forms.js module wrong, or is there an alternative?

I am aware of the type="text" solutions out there and then use https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker, but is that really the only solution I have available? I also need to sometimes use datetime inputs, which the angularjs does not have an example of, however type="datetime-local" works as I want it to, except in IE.

I am using version 1.6.6 of Angular.

Comment: what version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: I've updated original post now, but 1.6.6

Comment: On Opera works fine?